# How to use 2 sim cards & SD Card?

Tags: xiaomi, dual-sim

I have xiaomi redmi note 5 pro, and the sim tray has a hybrid configuration, Either using 2 sim cards or 1 sim and one micro sd card.
Is it anyway to use 2 sim cards and a micro SD card in the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to do all of this in the phone, but you could insert both sim cards to the phone and use an SD to USB adapter.